# Standalone Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bit trouble here. I need to have a bluetooth device (preferably cheap) to be placed on my room. Then I want my buddy phone to pick up and pair with that bluetooth device. I have developed a program for Android that is basically to check if the phone is paired to the unique MAC address the bluetooth device have. The rest of the stuff will be handled by the program on the phone.

The trouble is: I can't find any bluetooth device that could run itself on a certain voltage (I dont mind any since its on a PSU) What I've tried so far is the USB Dongle. It won't work without being connected to the PC whatsoever. By it won't work, I mean I can't search for it in my buddy phone when it is not connected to a PC. Another thing is an A2DP Bluetooth Dongle. It works, but my buddy phone also goes to silent since all the audio output goes to the A2DP.

Anyone can help me find a bluetooth device that can run itself? I don't need re programmable stuff since it will be used only for verification.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them" I **never** asked for places to purchase them, please re-read.
I don't know what's wrong with the question. My goal in this question is just to find what works by sharing what didn't works to me. If I already known that "tiny board" thing is a HC-05 or in other name a Bluetooth Module or if that thing will work, I wouldn't ask. Just now I also discovered that they did include one of those HC-05 inside of my toolbox.

Comment: "USB Dongle [...] won't work without being connected to the PC" That's because dongles don't include a Bluetooth stack, just a radio.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah, now I see why it doesn't shows up in my buddy phone.

Comment: Try HC-05 or any other simple Bluetooth device with SPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a Bluetooth device so you can pair your phone (or any other Bluetooth device), you can use the FC-114 alias HC-05 device:

- [Buy it in Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=HC-05)
- [Buy it in Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/hc-05)

It's a very simple device that you can connect using 5V power supply. It is designed to connect a microcontroller to it via serial communication. Microcontroller is not mandatory if your sole requirement is to pair your phone to it.

Depending on firmware variation, its pairing code is 1234 or 0000.

Here is a connection diagram:

[image: HC-05 as standalone device]

There are a variety of manufacturers of HC-05 / FC-144. Depending on which one you buy, all devices in the same batch may share the same MAC address, which can be annoying depending on your application. These devices have so called *AT-MODE* which allows to configure them using a UART to transmit commands to the RxD/TxD connectors.

UART devices are available as embedded in a Microprocessor, or as a [USB to UART adapter](https://www.google.ch/search?q=usb%20to%20uart%20adapter&tbm=isch). As Ignacio mentions, command AT+BIND is able to set the Bluetooth address ([See the communication protocol, page 10](http://www.linotux.ch/arduino/HC-0305_serial_module_AT_commamd_set_201104_revised.pdf)). I do not believe that the configured address is kept in Flash.

Comment: Grounding the RX connection of a UART is a bad idea since it is active *low*.

Comment: Right. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: Will this work as you intended? This is the only thing I can find from typing HC-05 http://i.stack.imgur.com/qW7Pm.jpg or if dead link http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12rn5LVXXXXa3aXXXq6xXFXXXw/Bluetooth-Serial-Transceiver-Module-Base-Board-For-HC-06-HC-07-HC-05-orArduino-MEGA-2560.jpg_640x640.jpg

Comment: I'm correcting the diagram after comment from Ignacio. It will allow you to pair your phone and nothing else. You're only interested in pairing, right?

Comment: @jmgonet Yes. I only need the phone to detect its unique MAC Address. Nothing else. Will the one that I posted works?

Comment: Yes. It looks like the same device. There are lots of variations around hc-05. They differ about details in communication with microcontroller, but this won't matter to you. I bought mine in amazon. Do you have access to it?

Comment: @jmgonet Have access to what? If what you mean by having access to the device, yes my campus have some of those but I never know what are they and how they works. Will give it a shot later with your updated schematics.

Comment: I've uploaded the correction. In amazon or ebay you can buy hc-05 for as little as 3$. I've given some links in my answer.

Comment: @jmgonet Thanks mate! One more question. If I have more than a room, ie I have 10 rooms with each own HC-05, will they all have different MAC Address? Some people wrote that they bought HC-05 in bulk and all of them have the same address.

Comment: You should be able to set the MAC address via the serial connection, but I don't know if the change will be permanent.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've edited my answer to reflect your comment. As HC-05 come from such variety of manufacturers and have so many different firmwares, it is always difficult to say for sure. There is a AT+BIND command that should allow it.