# Connecting to HC-05 from iOS based device

Tags: bluetooth

Continuing from [Standalone Bluetooth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248430/standalone-bluetooth) my project is almost complete.

For any of you who haven't seen that, here's a short info:
I'm trying to make an automated list of attendees by using a program that runs on a smartphone that can detect the HC-05.

So far it's all good, good only on Android based smartphones. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with iOS based devices. [I've read several posts around that iOS based devices can't see the HC-05 because of the limitation in their bluetooth rules.](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT204387)

But, in every single post that **"I've read"** there's none of em that talks about the solution. I want to know if there's any workaround for this? Or should I change to another bluetooth module? If anyone need more info I could provide everything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ios can control the hc-05 look.
https://youtu.be/iWH62g-eO_o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no workaround. HC-05 simply doesn't work with iOS, because iOS only supports [a few Bluetooth profiles](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387). This is because Apple uses [MFi Licensing Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

What does work is [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy). It's not part of MFi.

In other words: it's either dumping the iOS device or changing to a different Bluetooth profile.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now, if I choose to move to the BLE, can you name a few since I'm new to this bluetooth stuff? And does the BLE have a MAC Address? Since my program detects the HC-05 just by the way it scans for nearby BT MAC Address.

Comment: I haven't worked with Bluetooth before, so I'm not completely sure but BLE shoud have a MAC address. BLE is also used in those beacons you can attach to products so you can find them again. 

As for specific components I have nothing specific, but I'm sure there are many articles about BLE and devies that work with it.

Good luck!

Comment: HM-10 and HM-11 are the BLE brothers of HC-05/06, and rumor has it that they work fine with iOs and Android - give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

As is stated above, the Hc-05 isn't compatible with iOS because it's not certified under their licensing. BLE devices work, regardless of the brand - so I recommend using either the HM-10, or another CC2541 type BLE module. You can also look into the NRF51xx or NRF8001. I personally like the HM-10 because of the versatile nature, as well as a nice low-power sleep mode. I wrote several articles about the HM-10, including one about sending data to an iPhone:

[Sending a String via the HM-10 Bluetooth Module](https://engineersportal.com/blog/2017/9/20/hm-10-bluetooth-module?rq=hm%2010)